# How to achieve auto width Column in sap.ui.table.Table?

Tags: sapui5

I am using `sap.ui.table.Table`. This table has some very good feature but I am having a tough time to figure out how to set the column to auto width.

Currently, all the columns are fixed size but I want something if *column A* value is small, then auto adjust it rather than having fixed size. Same for if the column value is large, then adjust it to show the value.

I saw the other question [sap.ui.table.Table how to optimize column widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651001/sap-ui-table-table-how-to-optimize-column-widths) but the answers there are to get column layout with fixed sizes, not auto width.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sap.ui.table.Table how to optimize column widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651001/sap-ui-table-table-how-to-optimize-column-widths)

Comment: @n01dea - those answers are to get column layout with fix sizes, not auto width. Let me know if I am getting this wrong. Thanks

Comment: Is this issue still relevant? What is missing from the below answer? Are the columns supposed to adjust themselves automatically on scroll depending on the content?

Answer (score 0):

The control [`sap.ui.table.Column`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Column/controlProperties) offers a property called `autoResizable` by which the user can resize the column width depending on the content of the column's template.

```
<Column
  autoResizable="true"
  ...
```

From API Reference:

> Enables auto-resizing of the column on double clicking the resize bar. The width is determined on the widest **currently displayed content**. It does not consider rows which are currently not scrolled into view.

However, as you can see, it requires user interaction. Doing it without user interaction programmatically can be achieved by using the (currently experimental) API [`autoResizeColumn` from sap.ui.table.Table](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/methods/autoResizeColumn).

```
myTable.autoResizeColumn(/*ColumnIndex*/); // experimental!
```

Here is an example of both approaches: [https://embed.plnkr.co/NQpkJo/](https://embed.plnkr.co/NQpkJo/?show=view/Table.view.xml,preview).